# extract specific element from string in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have to extract data after executing commands on shell. I am able to execute command and capture output in the form of string. Below is the sample string output from which I have to extract each field of "uptime" command output e.g Last restart occurred at, Time since restart etc. I tried to convert it in dictionary but applied method is not working.

**Sample String:**

> b'\r\n\r\n  adjDisc/, adjprov/, ains/, alarm/, alatypes/, almBase/, ALPL/, alrmst, ALSO/, \r\n  applblki/, aTrace/, BackPlane/, baseUtils/, brownout/, bwm/, cac/, cdb/, \r\n  chkpt/, CLAF/, clustering/, cmnfpga/, comms/, config/, configFile/, control/, \r\n  cpl, cplutils/, create_file, csclient/, dasm_cfm/, datasync/, dbalrms/, \r\n  dbman/, dbrst/, ddf/, decommission/, diag/, difReasons, doc/, dov/, ds1tm/, \r\n  dsbl/, edf, ehf/, epl/, EqptAttr/, eqptgrp/, eqpt_mode/, eqpt_stats/, \r\n  eslots/, fhgraph/, filesync/, flashBurn/, flightrec/, fpo/, fsm/, ftp/, \r\n  ftpClient/, gzip/, hal/, hdsmlinkdata/, heapStats, httpc/, i2c/, imon/, ins/, \r\n  intDiag/, intrrpts/, ipc/, ipm/, irq1/, irq2/, IRQ6/, isc/, l2Services/, \r\n  leds/, loadinfo/, loadMgmt/, logs/, lua/, manufacturing/, memStats, \r\n  misconnection/, mmon/, mofshadow/, nbi_common_utils/, necht/, niapp/, nlc/, \r\n  nncli/, oamfac/, obm/, observer/, opmCtrl/, opmCtrlFlex/, OSRP/, otdr/, \r\n  owireci/, passive_slots/, pathopt/, pbe/, pdns/, PhotonicNBI/, \r\n  photonicsNVSRecovery/, photonic_ots/, photop/, plog/, PM/, pm/, pmbase/, \r\n  pmp/, pods/, powerAudit/, pramUtil/, ras/, RASDBGI, rdbg, rmcemon/, \r\n  round_trip_delay/, rpr/, rtrvlog/, sbf/, scmpml/, secure_erase_cmn/, \r\n  setpriv, shelfinfo/, shelfSync/, slc/, slotseq/, snmp/, SNMPTranslator/, \r\n  socKernel/, socLa/, SONMP/, sorn/, sov/, spfpga/, spsid_dump, \r\n  SpSwSubFailReason, spsync/, sptools/, svrest/, sync/, tar/, targetshell/, \r\n  tcsdebug/, tdrf/, tdrfShow, teas/, telnet/, tidci/, tl1ci/, TL1EvtSeq/, \r\n  tl1_to_avp/, tod/, top/, tpUtl/, tr/, trace/, tracepoints/, TRCntrl/, \r\n  ts1forn/, tsam/, tsbase/, tsds3ec1/, tsemotr/, tsexer/, tsfpo/, tsl2/, \r\n  tsmdd_qry/, tsm_prov/, tsm_sbf/, tsngm/, tsocn/, tsotnsw/, tsplug/, tsprot/, \r\n  tsprsta/, tssmux/, tsstm1ee4/, tsxc_sbf/, ts_allocation/, ud2_fwd/, udp_fwd/, \r\n  upgrade/, uptime, vbus/, vfs/, vfs_signal_debug/, vkgcct/, vkgfan/, vkginv/, \r\n  vkgio/, vkgpwr/, vk_i2c_acc/, vneProxy/, vosa/, *=quit\r\n\r\nTID="Sub_6500_3":Shelf=1\r\nSlot15-docInst: unset, ome_sp2_vx_appl: OME1280.BP\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:42 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> ~ uptime \r\nLast restart occurred at: FRI MAY 27, 2022 at 07:42:31 (UTC) \r\nTime since restart: 10 days 21 hrs 16 mins 13 secs\r\n\r\nActual Cumulative uptime: 489 days 7 hrs 30 mins\r\nLogged Cumulative uptime: 488 days 11 hrs 54 mins\r\n\r\nActual Continuous uptime: 118 days 15 hrs 47 mins\r\n\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:44 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> '

Comment: can you post the code you have tried

Comment: letter `b` indicate byte-like string, you convert to regular string with `the_bytes.decode()` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/byte-objects-vs-string-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you receive is of type `bytes`. Call its `decode()` method to transform it to a `str`.

Iterate through each line of the string and set a flag (`uptime_output_reached`) once the `uptime` output has started. Once that flag has been set, the following lines will be split into 2 strings at the first occurrence of `:` . These will be the key, value pairs used to store the uptime results.

What did you attempt? Edit your question with the code you tried, even if it didn't work.

```py
output_bytes = b'\r\n\r\n  adjDisc/, adjprov/, ains/, alarm/, alatypes/, almBase/, ALPL/, alrmst, ALSO/, \r\n  applblki/, aTrace/, BackPlane/, baseUtils/, brownout/, bwm/, cac/, cdb/, \r\n  chkpt/, CLAF/, clustering/, cmnfpga/, comms/, config/, configFile/, control/, \r\n  cpl, cplutils/, create_file, csclient/, dasm_cfm/, datasync/, dbalrms/, \r\n  dbman/, dbrst/, ddf/, decommission/, diag/, difReasons, doc/, dov/, ds1tm/, \r\n  dsbl/, edf, ehf/, epl/, EqptAttr/, eqptgrp/, eqpt_mode/, eqpt_stats/, \r\n  eslots/, fhgraph/, filesync/, flashBurn/, flightrec/, fpo/, fsm/, ftp/, \r\n  ftpClient/, gzip/, hal/, hdsmlinkdata/, heapStats, httpc/, i2c/, imon/, ins/, \r\n  intDiag/, intrrpts/, ipc/, ipm/, irq1/, irq2/, IRQ6/, isc/, l2Services/, \r\n  leds/, loadinfo/, loadMgmt/, logs/, lua/, manufacturing/, memStats, \r\n  misconnection/, mmon/, mofshadow/, nbi_common_utils/, necht/, niapp/, nlc/, \r\n  nncli/, oamfac/, obm/, observer/, opmCtrl/, opmCtrlFlex/, OSRP/, otdr/, \r\n  owireci/, passive_slots/, pathopt/, pbe/, pdns/, PhotonicNBI/, \r\n  photonicsNVSRecovery/, photonic_ots/, photop/, plog/, PM/, pm/, pmbase/, \r\n  pmp/, pods/, powerAudit/, pramUtil/, ras/, RASDBGI, rdbg, rmcemon/, \r\n  round_trip_delay/, rpr/, rtrvlog/, sbf/, scmpml/, secure_erase_cmn/, \r\n  setpriv, shelfinfo/, shelfSync/, slc/, slotseq/, snmp/, SNMPTranslator/, \r\n  socKernel/, socLa/, SONMP/, sorn/, sov/, spfpga/, spsid_dump, \r\n  SpSwSubFailReason, spsync/, sptools/, svrest/, sync/, tar/, targetshell/, \r\n  tcsdebug/, tdrf/, tdrfShow, teas/, telnet/, tidci/, tl1ci/, TL1EvtSeq/, \r\n  tl1_to_avp/, tod/, top/, tpUtl/, tr/, trace/, tracepoints/, TRCntrl/, \r\n  ts1forn/, tsam/, tsbase/, tsds3ec1/, tsemotr/, tsexer/, tsfpo/, tsl2/, \r\n  tsmdd_qry/, tsm_prov/, tsm_sbf/, tsngm/, tsocn/, tsotnsw/, tsplug/, tsprot/, \r\n  tsprsta/, tssmux/, tsstm1ee4/, tsxc_sbf/, ts_allocation/, ud2_fwd/, udp_fwd/, \r\n  upgrade/, uptime, vbus/, vfs/, vfs_signal_debug/, vkgcct/, vkgfan/, vkginv/, \r\n  vkgio/, vkgpwr/, vk_i2c_acc/, vneProxy/, vosa/, *=quit\r\n\r\nTID="Sub_6500_3":Shelf=1\r\nSlot15-docInst: unset, ome_sp2_vx_appl: OME1280.BP\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:42 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> ~ uptime \r\nLast restart occurred at: FRI MAY 27, 2022 at 07:42:31 (UTC) \r\nTime since restart: 10 days 21 hrs 16 mins 13 secs\r\n\r\nActual Cumulative uptime: 489 days 7 hrs 30 mins\r\nLogged Cumulative uptime: 488 days 11 hrs 54 mins\r\n\r\nActual Continuous uptime: 118 days 15 hrs 47 mins\r\n\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:44 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> '
output = output_bytes.decode()

uptime_output_reached = False
uptime_results = {}

for line in output.splitlines():
    if line == "----> ~ uptime ":
        uptime_output_reached = True
        continue
    
    if uptime_output_reached:
        if ": " in line:
            key, value = line.split(": ", 1)
            uptime_results[key] = value

print("uptime results:")
for key, value in uptime_results.items():
    print(f"'{key}': '{value}'")
```

Output:

```
uptime results:
'Last restart occurred at': 'FRI MAY 27, 2022 at 07:42:31 (UTC) '
'Time since restart': '10 days 21 hrs 16 mins 13 secs'
'Actual Cumulative uptime': '489 days 7 hrs 30 mins'
'Logged Cumulative uptime': '488 days 11 hrs 54 mins'
'Actual Continuous uptime': '118 days 15 hrs 47 mins'
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative as @GordonAitchJay described, you can use `regexp` something like this:

```
sample = b'\r\n\r\n  adjDisc/, adjprov/, ains/, alarm/, alatypes/, almBase/, ALPL/, alrmst, ALSO/, \r\n  applblki/, aTrace/, BackPlane/, baseUtils/, brownout/, bwm/, cac/, cdb/, \r\n  chkpt/, CLAF/, clustering/, cmnfpga/, comms/, config/, configFile/, control/, \r\n  cpl, cplutils/, create_file, csclient/, dasm_cfm/, datasync/, dbalrms/, \r\n  dbman/, dbrst/, ddf/, decommission/, diag/, difReasons, doc/, dov/, ds1tm/, \r\n  dsbl/, edf, ehf/, epl/, EqptAttr/, eqptgrp/, eqpt_mode/, eqpt_stats/, \r\n  eslots/, fhgraph/, filesync/, flashBurn/, flightrec/, fpo/, fsm/, ftp/, \r\n  ftpClient/, gzip/, hal/, hdsmlinkdata/, heapStats, httpc/, i2c/, imon/, ins/, \r\n  intDiag/, intrrpts/, ipc/, ipm/, irq1/, irq2/, IRQ6/, isc/, l2Services/, \r\n  leds/, loadinfo/, loadMgmt/, logs/, lua/, manufacturing/, memStats, \r\n  misconnection/, mmon/, mofshadow/, nbi_common_utils/, necht/, niapp/, nlc/, \r\n  nncli/, oamfac/, obm/, observer/, opmCtrl/, opmCtrlFlex/, OSRP/, otdr/, \r\n  owireci/, passive_slots/, pathopt/, pbe/, pdns/, PhotonicNBI/, \r\n  photonicsNVSRecovery/, photonic_ots/, photop/, plog/, PM/, pm/, pmbase/, \r\n  pmp/, pods/, powerAudit/, pramUtil/, ras/, RASDBGI, rdbg, rmcemon/, \r\n  round_trip_delay/, rpr/, rtrvlog/, sbf/, scmpml/, secure_erase_cmn/, \r\n  setpriv, shelfinfo/, shelfSync/, slc/, slotseq/, snmp/, SNMPTranslator/, \r\n  socKernel/, socLa/, SONMP/, sorn/, sov/, spfpga/, spsid_dump, \r\n  SpSwSubFailReason, spsync/, sptools/, svrest/, sync/, tar/, targetshell/, \r\n  tcsdebug/, tdrf/, tdrfShow, teas/, telnet/, tidci/, tl1ci/, TL1EvtSeq/, \r\n  tl1_to_avp/, tod/, top/, tpUtl/, tr/, trace/, tracepoints/, TRCntrl/, \r\n  ts1forn/, tsam/, tsbase/, tsds3ec1/, tsemotr/, tsexer/, tsfpo/, tsl2/, \r\n  tsmdd_qry/, tsm_prov/, tsm_sbf/, tsngm/, tsocn/, tsotnsw/, tsplug/, tsprot/, \r\n  tsprsta/, tssmux/, tsstm1ee4/, tsxc_sbf/, ts_allocation/, ud2_fwd/, udp_fwd/, \r\n  upgrade/, uptime, vbus/, vfs/, vfs_signal_debug/, vkgcct/, vkgfan/, vkginv/, \r\n  vkgio/, vkgpwr/, vk_i2c_acc/, vneProxy/, vosa/, *=quit\r\n\r\nTID="Sub_6500_3":Shelf=1\r\nSlot15-docInst: unset, ome_sp2_vx_appl: OME1280.BP\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:42 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> ~ uptime \r\nLast restart occurred at: FRI MAY 27, 2022 at 07:42:31 (UTC) \r\nTime since restart: 10 days 21 hrs 16 mins 13 secs\r\n\r\nActual Cumulative uptime: 489 days 7 hrs 30 mins\r\nLogged Cumulative uptime: 488 days 11 hrs 54 mins\r\n\r\nActual Continuous uptime: 118 days 15 hrs 47 mins\r\n\r\nCommand completed at TUE JUN 07, 2022 - 04:58:44 (UTC)\r\n\r\n----> '

import re

match = re.search( r'---->(.+?)---->', sample.decode(), re.S )
uptime = match[1] if match else ''

print( uptime )
```